# How do I extract text from dwg?

Tags: autocad

I'm trying to convert data from an AUtoCad Civil 3d drawing to a text format to use in ArcGIS. Each dwg has coordinate and text information that I would like to use for point location and attributes. The text looks to be a table but is in fact just mtext and line objects.
I have found LISP code that will export all the mtext to a text file but I am wondering if there is a way to place all the text found at the same xy location in the dwg to be placed on one line in the text file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can export dwg file to arcgis using ArcCatalog, following these steps:

- if you need to export the center of the text as position resize all the text (annotation) , set the size to 0.001 for eg (the smallest as possible), if not the position upper left corner will be exported.
- browse the dwg file with arcCatalog open it you will find 'annotations' this part contains text and their positions, so it should be exported to .shp file.
- in arcgis level you will open the .shp file and find the text as 'textmemo' or "text" columns.

i wish it could help